# Java: Ways to test multiple static methods without repeating the test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static

I have a class factorial
inside it is two static methods:

factorialImperative() & factorialRecursion,

is there a way to test both of those without having to repeat the test for each method?

I want to see if there's a way to do it without violating the DRY principle.

Comment: It's quite easy in Spock but a little more clumsy (and with worse reporting) in plain JUnit. Hint: You'll want to use a functional interface.

Comment: So I did try implementing an interface. Basically an interface containing the test for both method. Then another test class that implements the interface and from that I'm stuck. Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one unit test tests one "unit" of  software, usually one method. This is done to quickly isolate a problem if test fails.
If you have unit test which calls only one method and test fails then the issue is obviously in that method.
If you have unit test with several methods then in general case you will need to investigate deeper to understand where the issue is. And even more if tour test has several asserts because you want to check output of several methods then if the first assert fails then all other asserts will not be even executed.
To show an example

```
public void testFactorials() {
    Assert.assertEquals(6, factorialImperative(3));
    Assert.assertEquals(6, factorialRecursion(3));
}
```

If the test above fails on the first assert you will know nothing about the correctness of the second method.

You can try to do the following though

```
public void testBoth() {
    Assert.assertEquals(factorialImperative(10), factorialRecursion(10));
}
```

But in this case if both methods have integer overflow you will not be able to catch it.